# The use of the definite article with item names

Tags: definite-article

Do I need to use **the definite article** in the following instance?

(R&A stands for a company, CA122 - an item name)

> We`d like to cancel the order for **the** R&A CA122.

Comment: That is not a sentence, and therefore we cannot assume what you want to say - ultimately, we do not know if the article is correct or not. Please edit the answer and provide the full sentence.

Comment: It's all a bit flexible. As a rule of thumb, the more we think of *[item name]* a representing *an actual **physical** object* - as opposed to primarily being *[an instantiation of] a **concept or technology*** - the more we're likely to include an article. For a referent that kinda spans both associations, consider ***Amazon Alexa*** (where the article *is* normally included when referencing the ***physical product***, but it's *not* so likely to be included when referencing it as the embodiment of a ***technology***.

Comment: @virolino why do you say that the example isn't a full sentence. It looks like one to me?

Answer (score 0):

It's all a bit flexible. As a rule of thumb, the more we think of [item name] a representing an actual physical object - as opposed to primarily being [an instantiation of] a concept or technology - the more we're likely to include an article. For a referent that kinda spans both associations, consider Amazon Alexa (where the article is normally included when referencing the physical product, but it's not so likely to be included when referencing it as the embodiment of a technology. – FumbleFingers

Answer (score 0):

> We'd like to cancel the order for the Acme model 2850.

I would use "the" before acme here whether a 2850 is a bicycle or a piece of software or a service contract. It is the specific thing that was ordered. Even when not referring to the proeprties of the item generally I would still often use an article:

> The Acme 2850 databas is much more reliable than the Zorro 3410.

But not always:

> Acme 2850 is an excellent value.

But one could also say:

> The Acme 2850 is an excellent value.

Of course it isn't always a definite article:

> I just got an Acme 2850, ant it is really great.
>
> I had to set up some Acme 2850s, and it was a tricky job.

(By the way, do **not** use "Acme 2850's" as a plural, that should only be used for a possesive form. Many people get this wrong.)

When using a fully generic term, an article can be omitted:

> - Lasers have a wide variety of uses.
> - Databases improved business operations.
> - Bicycles allow messengers to cover much more ground in an hour.

This is true whether the thing is physical or not, in my view.

By the way

> We`d like to cancel the order for the R&A CA122.

is a complete sentence, although what a CA122 **is** would need context.